# Avoiding the warning: operation on ‘count’ may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

I'm working with the Node.js N-API and I'm making a little wrapper that will make exporting C++ functions easy.

```
template<class T, class... Targs> napi_value Api::create(const char* name, T (* const cb)(Targs...))
{
    // creates JavaScript function that will call cbProxy<> when called
    return create(name, cbProxy<T, Targs...>, cb);
}

template<class T, class... Targs> napi_value Api::cbProxy(const napi_env env, const napi_callback_info info)
{
    // number of arguments
    size_t count = sizeof...(Targs);
    ApiValue args[count];
    T (* cb)(Targs...);
    // retrieve arguments and callback
    if (!Api::getParams(env, info, args, count, &cb))
        return nullptr;

    T ret = cb(Api::getValue<Targs>(&args[--count])...);    
    return Api(env).create(ret);
}

template<> bool Api::getValue(ApiValue* value)
{
    return value->toBool();
}

template<> double Api::getValue(ApiValue* value)
{
    return value->toDouble();
}

template<> int32_t Api::getValue(ApiValue* value)
{
    return value->toInt32();
}
```

The idea is to call `api.create("TestFunction", testFn);` which will return a JS function.
When it's called, it will call `Api::cbProxy<>` which converts the JS parameters to the equivalent C++ types with `Api::getValue<T>()` and calls `testFn` (cb).

Lets say `testFn` has the following signature: `int testFn(bool bVal, double dVal)`
The line `T ret = cb(Api::getValue<Targs>(&args[--count])...);` will expand to

```
int ret = cb(Api::getValue<bool>(&args[--count]), 
             Api::getValue<double>(&args[--count]));
```

Which works 100% fine, but it triggers a compiler warning. I'm a bit of a novice regarding C++, so I'm looking for a better way to write this.

Basically I want to traverse the array `args` and the list of type parameters `Targs` at once.

Just to clarify: The `--count` in the expanded function call triggers the following warning:
`warning: operation on ‘count’ may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]`

Comment: And the warning is...?

Comment: @max66 As the title states, "warning: operation on ‘count’ may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined behavior and sequence points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)

Comment: Next time, whenever you find yourself saying something "works 100% fine, but...", I hope your second thought is "Nope. Something definitely wrong." But it is good you don't ignore warning.

Comment: @NickyC It relies on undefined behavior so it's 100% wrong, but I was unable to figure out another way.

Comment: The double `--count` here is at least well-defined in C++17, but still not a great story.

Comment: The `args` definition is a VLA non-standard extension; to fix this `count` should be `const`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that the problem is that in

```
int ret = cb(Api::getValue<bool>(&args[--count]), 
             Api::getValue<double>(&args[--count]));
```

the order of evaluation of argument argument is <s>implementation dependent</s> undefined bahaviour (M.M correction) so, given `count` starting from `2`, can be

```
int ret = cb(Api::getValue<bool>(&args[1]), 
             Api::getValue<double>(&args[0]));
```

or

```
int ret = cb(Api::getValue<bool>(&args[0]), 
             Api::getValue<double>(&args[1]));
```

To be sure that the first index of `args` (the `bool` one) is `1` and that the second one (the `double` one) is `0`, a possible way is use variadic indexes.

If you can use C++14, using a `cbProxyHelper()` method, you can try something as follows (caution: code not tested)

```
template <typename T, typename ... Targs, std::size_t ... Is>
napi_value Api::cbProxyHelper (const napi_env env,
                               const napi_callback_info info,
                               std::index_sequence<Is...> const &)
 {
   // number of arguments
   constexpr std::size_t count = sizeof...(Targs);
   ApiValue args[count];
   T (* cb)(Targs...);
   // retrieve arguments and callback
   if (!Api::getParams(env, info, args, count, &cb))
      return nullptr;

   T ret = cb(Api::getValue<Targs>(&args[count-1U-Is])...);    
   return Api(env).create(ret);
 }

template <typename T, typename ... Targs>
napi_value Api::cbProxy (const napi_env env, const napi_callback_info info)
 { return cbProxyHelper(env, info, std::index_sequence_for<Targs...>{}); }
```

If you're using C++11, simulate `std::index_sequence` and `std::make_index_sequence` isn't really difficult.

Comment: I figured the order of evaluation would give problems. Thanks for the really neat solution!

Comment: The original code was *undefined behaviour* prior to C++17  ; in C++17 it was changed to *unspecified* which behaves as you describe

Comment: @Smokey - You're welcome. Answer a little improved (aesthetically improved): `std::index_sequence_for` instead `std::make_index_sequence`.

Comment: @M.M - you're right: undefined behavior; I was convinced was implementation dependent. Corrected; thanks.